# Implementing a template Linked List class using arrow (->)

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I am having an issue with implementing a template Linked List class.
I've made linked lists before, but not as a template.

In the .cpp file (implementation) it seems that the member pointer variables aren't being recognized as members and using `->` after these pointers doesn't work.
There is no underline of syntax error anywhere near the issue, but when I highlight the variable, the description says "unknown" and the details of the variable

(What's even stranger is that nothing i place in the scope can get the underline syntax error.)

```
// ListLinked.h
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

template <typename DataType>
class List {
private:
    struct ListNode {
        DataType dataItem;
        ListNode* next;
    };

    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* cursor;

public:
    List(int ignored = 0);  
    List(const List& other);
    List& operator=(const List& other);
    ~List();                                    

    void insert(const DataType& newDataItem);
    void remove();                                  
    void replace(const DataType& newDataItem);
    void clear();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isFull() const;

    void gotoBeginning();                           
    void gotoEnd();                                 
    bool gotoNext();                                
    bool gotoPrior();                               

    void showStructure() const;

    DataType getCursor() const;                         
};

//ListLinked.cpp (just the simplest one of the many member functions that use ->)

template <typename DataType>
bool List<DataType>::gotoNext(){
if (cursor->next != NULL)      //"next" is not seen as a member pointer variable
    cursor = cursor->next;
}

// all the other member functions start with
// template <typename DataType>
// [type] List<DataType>:: {...}
```

I suspect that something is wrong with my visual express 2010, but i'm not sure

Comment: Try moving ListNode outside of List as a templated class on DataType, and make the cursor/head pointers ListNode<DataType>*. See if that fixes it, I suspect it is to do with scope visibility/template instantiation of that inner struct. Then work your way from there.

Answer (score 0):

When you use templated class/function, you need to have the whole implementation in source file. Put all the template reference to your .h file as a first move ;)

If you want to keep your header clean without the function code, you can create a  file named `linkedlist.impl` and put in your definition. At the end of your header, before your guard, add `#include "linkedlist.impl"`.